# Show div after complete progress bar jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I need a solution for my upload form with jquery progress bar. Everything works fine, but after uploading for example 8 big size images the progress bar is 100% but the page freezes untill the script has processed the files and than the redirect comes, the time between 100% and the redict sometimes takes several seconds and in those seconds i want to .show() a div with a text like: '1 moment, images are uploaded and will now be processed on the server' or something under the actual progressbar.

This is my progress bar:

```
(function() {

var bar = $('.bar');
var percent = $('.percent');
var status = $('#status');

$('form').ajaxForm({
beforeSend: function() {
    status.empty();
    var percentVal = '0%';
    bar.width(percentVal)
    percent.html(percentVal);
},
uploadProgress: function(event, position, total, percentComplete) {
    var percentVal = percentComplete + '%';
    bar.width(percentVal)
    percent.html(percentVal);


},
complete: function(xhr) {

  bar.width("100%");
  percent.html("100%");
  window.location.href = 'index.php';

}
}); 

})(); 



<div id="loadProgress"  style="display:none">
<div class="progress">
    <div class="bar"></div >
    <div class="percent">0%</div >
</div>

<div id="status"></div>
```

How can i make this work to show a div on 100% progress but keep the redirect after the whole progress is done intact?

Comment: if you are dealing with large images your page will hang for sure, you but slice the images data into smaller pieces and then pass it , also in your server side you need to concat the data. This way when you are passing small amount of data your page doesnt hang

Comment: Thanks for your reply! But how can i do this?

Comment: that would be alot of details to put in here. I would give some keywords and you can search on them, first `read the uploaded file byte array` , `split the image array into size 1MB each` , `blob the image and send it to server`, Then in server either maintain a session or global variable to which you save this data into. when the last array chunk is sent to server combine all the array and save the file.

Comment: OK thanks! This also be working for video i guess

Comment: It will work for any file upload.

Comment: Hi Reddy, i googled your sugesstions but this problem is to big for me! Can you help me to integrate it in my code when i post my simple upload form? I basicicly need a very simple chunk function with a fallback to the old upload form. No fancy stuff.

Comment: Hi, what do you mean by `I basicicly need a very simple chunk function with a fallback to the old upload form. No fancy stuff.`

Comment: I want after your advice to slice images, rebuild my upload form for uploading images/videos in slices/chunks but have no idea how to do this, even solutions like Resumable.js is to hard for me to be honest. So can i maybe send you my upload form to take a look at it?, i will apreciate it a lot!.After googling 'slicing' i found out that it will be a  nessecary thing for my site because it will be used for news fotagraphers who upload images on mobile devices

Comment: @DavJ I will be happy to help you out But I dont think I can make it quick, Can you wait? Like I will create a POC and then share with you.

Comment: Thanks alot! Is there a way to connect tot you? My mail is davejansen79 [a] gmail , and i'm in no hurry!!

Comment: ok sure, Let me know how much time you have, Also if your server side code is php I am of no good help to you over there, But jquery surely yes

Comment: I have several weeks.. But the upload form is php.

Comment: So here's the deal I can help you out with Jquery part, you take care of the php one. sounds good?

Comment: OK.. Basicly, its a simpele form with 8 seperate fileinputs(no multiple input for CSS cosmetics reasons) and two text inputs, if you can write a jquery part to handle 8 seperate file inputs limited on jpg,png,mp4,mov  and 2 text input sends to an AJAX, then i will figure out how to integrate it in a PHP script. Thanks in advance!

Comment: ok, Ill see what best can be done.